# Ionic Cordova adding native Firebase: Missing Command Error

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

Angular 7,
Ionic 4.12.0,
Cordova: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1).

After adding `Firebase` and `FirebaseAuthentication` from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase
I dont see these plugins added in my config.xml.

When I try to use any method from FirebaseAuthentication I have the following error:

> Error: exec proxy not found for :: FirebaseAuthentication ::
>   createUserWithEmailAndPassword

The code:

```
export class FirebaseGeneralService {

    constructor(private _firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuthentication, private firebase: Firebase, private platform: Platform) {
        this.init();
    }

    private async init() {
        this.platform.ready().then(
            async () => {
                await this._firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("test@test.com", "123456");
            }
        );
    }
}
```

in my module Ive added `providers: [..., Firebase, FirebaseAuthentication]`

Now, when I debug the code to inside of cordova.js (line 1038), I come across this line:

```
return (CommandProxyMap[service] ? CommandProxyMap[service][action] : null);

CommandProxyMap doesnt contain neither `Firebase` or `FirebaseAuthentication`. Ive attached an image showing the line and object content.
```

[image: note the FirebaseAuthentication service behind the tooltip]

Ive tried to add the plugins manually to the config.xml file:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="5.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication" spec="5.5.1" />
```

(just a reminder, ive installed them properly from the CLI. both Firebase and FirebaseAuthentication).

This is a runtime error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase` ?

Comment: i wrote i did. but i also said that it didnt add it to config.xml